# displaying an image from a file chooser

Tags: java, image, swing

I am having problems displaying an image I obtain from a file chooser I created. Could you give me suggestions? The image is created as a buffered image.

Here is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource().getClass().getName().contains("JMenuItem")) 
    {
        if (e.paramString().contains("Load")) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
            int retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (retVal == 0) 
            {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                image = ImageIO.read(file);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for display:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){  
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawImage(getIconImage(), 0, 0, control);
    g.drawImage( image, 0, 0,null);
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: What problems exactly are you having?

Comment: what errors do you get? why are you calling drawImage twice? could you post the whole code or an SSCCE or at least the stacktrace reporting the error?

Comment: the think is the image does not show on my gui. I want to display the image i obtain from the file chooser to my gui. Do you want to see the code for my gui?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638988/problem-with-loading-image-in-java-with-filechooser this question has similar problem, look thru it! give yourself at least 1 hour than you will not forgot how to do this in your entire life :)

Comment: the display code doesn't look like Swing ... in case you are mixing awt and swing - dont!

Comment: repaint() in a paint method? Just don't do it!  Myself, I like mKorbel's solution (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Why bothering with 2D Graphics for display picture(s), put [Image/ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), example about [JFileChooser + Image + paintCompoent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993467/how-to-rotate-jximagepanel/6993818#6993818),

```
public void paint(Graphics g){// paintComponent not paint 
   super.paintComponents(g);  // paintComponent not paintComponents
.....
```

Could be for Swing `JComponent`s

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){  
   super.paintComponent(g);
......
```

Comment: +1 There's a nice scaling example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916693/jmenuitem-imageicon-too-big).